Is a static_cast from a base to derived class well-defined when both classes have the same layout?
I would like to create C++ bindings for a C API. Would the following be undefined behavior?
typedef struct ABC_Foo { int x_; } ABC_Foo;

namespace abc {

class Foo : public ABC_Foo {
public:
  int x() const { return x_; }
};
static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(ABC_Foo));
}

#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

int main() {
  ABC_Foo cfoo = {42};
  // Is this UB?
  abc::Foo const& cppfoo = *std::launder(static_cast<abc::Foo*>(&cfoo));
  printf("%d\n", cppfoo.x());
}

godbolt link
I am expecting well-defined behavior, since abc::Foo and ABC_Foo are equivalent and I have laundered the pointer, even though cppfoo was never actually constructed as an abc::Foo.

EDIT: user17732522 provided me with a solution. To use a struct that has been initialized in C as a C++ class with the same memory layout, I should use std::start_lifetime_as<T>(void*). (In this case, I would use composition instead of inheritance, too.)
class Foo { ABC_Foo cfoo_; ...}; static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(ABC_Foo));
...
ABC_Foo cfoo = {42};
abc::Foo* cppfoo = std::start_lifetime_as<abc::Foo>(&cfoo);
// Accessing cppfoo is well-defined now, but accessing cfoo would
// violate aliasing rules.


Pretty sure this will violate the strict aliasing rule.

Is this UB? Yes, it is.

Laundering only works if you have constructed an object of type T but you for some reason have a U* pointing to the address and you want to obtain a T*.  It doesn't mean that you can obtain a valid (dereferencable) U* to a memory that in fact holds a T.

As it stands, this has UB--but I believe you can get defined behavior slightly differently.
typedef struct ABC_Foo { int x_; } ABC_Foo;

namespace abc {

class Foo {
  int x_;
public:
  int x() const { return x_; }
};
static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == sizeof(ABC_Foo));
}

union foo {
    ABC_foo c;
    abc::foo cpp;
};

In a union you're allowed to access the common initial sequence of the union from any member of the union, so (for example) writing to ABC_Foo::x_ and reading from abc::Foo::x_ (or vice versa) is allowed.

@user17732522: Oops-missed a minor edit.

Ah ok, yes with the edit the behavior is defined. The static_assert isn't even needed. The problem will be that OP seems to want to retrieve the object from the C side which won't know about the union type. So cfoo probably can't be created as a foo union or member of one.

Unfortunately, this won't work for what I'm trying to do. I intend to allocate an object in C code compiled with a C compiler (meaning I can't create a union w/ the C++ type), then pass it to C++ library that will operate on it via C++ bindings.

The cast static_cast<abc::Foo*>(&cfoo) itself has undefined behavior if &cfoo isn't actually a pointer to a ABC_Foo object which is the base class subobject of some Foo object.
You never did anything to implicitly or explicitly created a Foo object anywhere, so the requirement above is not satisfied and the cast has undefined behavior.
std::launder doesn't make it better at all. Aside from the cast expression itself already being UB anyway, std::launder also has a precondition that an object of the pointed-to-type must be alive at the address represented by the pointer argument. Since you never created any Foo object, the call to std::launder is again UB.
std::launder is never useful when casting with static_cast between (non-void*) pointers. std::launder only becomes relevant when reintepret_casting between pointers or when static_casting to a different pointer type through void* (which is what reinterpret_cast is defined to do as well).

Makes sense. Sounds like I should be using a reinterpret_cast then. The example at the bottom of this page suggests that it's well-defined behavior: auto p1 = reinterpret_cast<S*>(&s1);

@JimCarroll No, it is just as much UB. You simply can't form a pointer/reference to some type X if you haven't created an object of type X (explicitly or implicitly) first. C++ doesn't allow that.

@JimCarroll The example on the page is casting from the derived to the base class. That way around is easy and static_cast should be used. The other way around is also possible with static_cast, but only if an object of the derived type was actually created initially (which isn't the case in your example). reinterpret_cast to cast in class hierarchy has defined behavior only in very specific instances. Never use it for that purpose.

I see. Confusing that the docs would advertise an anti-pattern.
I suppose then following would work, so long as the abc::Foo constructor does not actually initialize the memory:
abc::Foo *cppfoo = new (&cfoo);
Now, I have a valid constructed abc::Foo object that can operate on the C object memory.

@JimCarroll No, that will also lead to undefined behavior. Formally new creates a new object with indeterminate value, regardless of what state the memory was in beforehand. What you would want is abc::Foo *cppfoo =  std::start_lifetime_as<abc::Foo>(&cfoo) and then you would want to use only the cppfoo pointer from there on. Make sure to follow the restrictions placed on start_lifetime_as. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as. In particular you need to assure that sizeof and alignof the types match and that abc::Foo is an implicit-lifetime type.

@JimCarroll However, in all of these UB considerations, one should also keep in mind, that the interaction between C and C++ is not specified at all. So, if you don't just ask about C++ code behavior, but behavior across C and C++ translation units, then everything will be up to the implementation anyway. Also a lot of this is UB, but happens to work (with certain constraints) in practice on every compiler.
